# Example of a function of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ in itself that is not polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I am trying to give an example of a function of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ in itself that is not polynomial. For that I thought to give some characterization of the polynomial functions of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ in itself. I took a polynomial $P\in \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}[X]$  such that $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i$ with $a_i\in \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$. Then:
$$
P(2)=a_12+a_0
$$
Then if $f$ is a function of $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(2)=1$. Then if $f$ is polynomial function so there is $P\in \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}[X]$  such that $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i$ and $f(x)=P(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$. But $$
f(0)=a_0=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad f(2)=a_1 2+a_0=a_1 2=1
$$
So $2\in (\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z})^{×}$. Contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: i made a mistake $f(2)=1$. thank you for your remark, @Oussema

Comment: No problem. Your proof looks correct to me. I thought a little bit about lagrange interpolation but then I remembered it doesn't guarantee that the coefficients will be integers.

Comment: In general, if $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $c,d$ are integers then $f(c)-f(d)$ will divide $c-d$. This fact has been used by you.

Comment: Oh dear, $c-d$ will divide $f(c)-f(d)$, pardon me (see above comment).